# Page not found (404) in django index page

Tags: python, django

I am new to django

I am following the tutorial to develop a poll application using django

But I am getting an error in my index page when I include url pattern to my poll app

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

but If comment the polls url no issues

my polls/urls page contain

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

Comment: A 404 when you go *where*?

Comment: in my index page itself..sry for late reply..I went for lunch

Comment: Do you mean `/`? You don't have a URL mapping for that.

Comment: could you please explain detail..what i need to do now..I have views.py file ..it contains    from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

Comment: when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I am getting this error..But i If comment url to my app..it works..

Comment: No, it's not possible that it could work if you simply uncomment your app. You *have no URL mapping* for `/`.

Comment: As per their documentation they did not give the url mapping for /.If give the url mapping for / to my app index view it is working fine..thanks..but can you  please go through the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/  and let me know what I missid..

Comment: You didn't miss anything. That tutorial tells you to go to `/polls/`.